is it permissible to make a website for stores in which there is liquor with other products as well
I am working on a web project in which there are multiple stores and basically we provide a feature that it gives you the best products according to the prices. For example if there is a same product in different stores than you can easily compare the prices across the stores and can find one with lower price or the one that suits you. It also has an AI feature that tells you about it.
Now my point of concern is that these stores also include alcoholic products, and there is a different category for it. But the main purpose of our application is not selling alcohol but to give products based on the prices.
So, I just want to clarify if it is permissible or not? Or if my earnings will be halal?
